# ZFS Unknown command via ssh, but is in $PATH

Tags: ssh, fish, zfs

I am trying to use `syncoid` to send a `zfs` dataset to a remote macOS machine, with [OpenZFS on macOS](https://openzfsonosx.org) installed.

During the run, I get the error: `fish: Unknown command: zfs`.

I can replicate this error with `ssh remotehost zfs --help`.

I thought that maybe `zfs` wasn't on my `PATH` from the perspective of the `ssh` session, but if I check with `ssh remotehost echo $PATH`, I can see `/usr/local/zfs/bin` listed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/zfs/bin` actually exist?  Is `/usr/local/zfs/bin` mounted?  Is `/usr/local/zfs/bin` readable?  Is there actually a `zfs` binary in `/usr/local/zfs/bin`?  Is that binary executable?

Comment: yes indeed, the line for `zfs` from `ls -la /usr/local/zfs/bin` reads `-rwxr-xr-x@  1 james  staff  179984  7 Dec  2022 zfs*`.

I can also use zfs locally on that machine, or after I ssh into the machine. I just can't use it in a one-shot where I postfix the command to the end of the ssh command.

Comment: When you execute `ssh remotehost echo $PATH` the PATH var is expanded on the local system. Try `ssh remotehost 'echo $PATH'`. I am confident you will see a different PATH that does not contain the directory where the `zfs` command lives.

Comment: @KurtisRader you're spot on, I feel silly now... Thank you. If you promote into an answer I'll give you the stack overflow credit.